# Can you give examples for the tips I listed about c11 standard's calloc to help me to understand them?

Tags: c, memory-management, c11, calloc

When I reading references about calloc in [calloc reference in cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) ,I found the following tips which I didn't get.

- **calloc** is thread-safe: it behaves as though only accessing the memory locations visible through its argument, and not any static storage.
- A previous call to **free** or **realloc** that deallocates a region of memory **synchronizes-with** a call to calloc that allocates the same or a part of the same region of memory. This synchronization occurs **after** any access to the memory by the deallocating function **and before** any access to the memory by calloc.

Can you give me examples to help to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

It just means that calloc will work just fine if you use it in a multi-threaded environment (lots of threads running at the same time, and all allocating or releasing or reallocating memory like crazy is no problem).

Since not all C and C++ functions make that kind of guarantee, it needs to be mentioned in the documentation. Usually you should assume that when thread safety isn't mentioned, it isn't thread safe.

Comment: I know a thing called **thread-safe** and I can pick it out when someone is talking about it,but I had little multi-thread programming practice.BTW,you forgot to tell me your opinions about the second tip in my question.